# Python CGI output contains the Angular ajax request object

Tags: python, ajax, angularjs, cgi

When I post data using Angularjs to a Python CGI script, I have a weird issue where the Python output contains an Angular object that I can't remove.

The Angular Javascript responsible for posting to the Python script:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/cgi-bin/test.py',
  data: "test"
})
.then(function(data){
  console.log(data)
})
```

The Python script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
print "Content-type: application/json"
print
```

The resulting console log should be empty, but this is what I see in the Chrome console:

[image: Console log contains angular object.]

I'm new to Python and Angular so I suspect that I've made a simple mistake, but I've been unable to find examples of this kind of behavior anywhere after a day of searching. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: no `data` is the response object ....

Comment: Okay, thanks! I should have used `console.log(data["data"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming from jQuery's ajax, I expected the response from Angular's http function to include only the returned data, so I was thrown off by the presence of config, status, header data, etc.

In order to isolate the data part of the response, I did this:

```
.then(function(response){
    data = response['data']
    console.log(data)
})
```